# When using Highcharts, how do you get the point name from a data point series?

Tags: highcharts, series, points

I've created a chart that has an array of objects with named values like the following

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

If I wanted to later look at back my data series later and get back the names "Point 1" and "Point 2", how would I do so?

I tried a function that iterates the data series like this:

```
var data = someSeries.data;

for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
{
    alert( data[i]['x'] );
}
```

which gets me each point, but obviously doesn't work since the x data is stored as a number (I tried doing an array with 2 values instead of the point configuration objects with similar results).  'name' is undefined for that data point as well.

Does the initial name that I entered when generating the series get saved anywhere for me to access?  Am I looking at the wrong object?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to reference data inside of the chart after initialization you need to reference the chart first.  Then access the name property like you would with any other object property.

```
var myData = myChartName.series[0].data;

for ( var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++ )
{
  alert( myData[i].name );
}
```

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question.  The someSeries that I have pulled the data from in my example is from iterating through the chart.series array, so 'someSeries' is actually in the format that you have in yours for 'myChartName'.  I tried referencing the data as you noted with the '.name' instead of ['name'], but I get "undefined" in my alert using either way.  The data is coming in correctly as I use it for categories from a django template dict and that works.  Perhaps the way I'm storing it when setting up the series data is wrong?

Comment: can you post a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/321/  are you getting other errors?

Comment: Actually, as I built my jfiddle for this, I realized I had a stupid logic error elsewhere.  This answer is the correct way to grab the data and it did help me narrow down where the other problem was.  As a note, it also works with ['name'] as I was trying to attempt.